# setting texture parameter across opengl contexts

Tags: opengl, egl

This is a follow-up question to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55886510).

If I have the following setup

```
eglMakeCurrent(,,,contextA); 
glCreateTextures(,texHandles);
...

eglMakeCurrent(,,,contextB);
glTextureParameterf(texHandles[0],,);
```

where `contextA` and `contextB` are shared contexts. Assuming that everything in the above snippet is correctly setup in accordance to the OpenGL spec. Should the call to set texture parameter succeed since texture object is not a container object?

Comment: This code has a bug that has nothing to do with context usage. `glGenTextures` only generates names; it doesn't create the object state for those names. `glTextureParameter` is a direct state access function; it only works on objects that have functional state. Which yours doesn't yet. As such, it would fail to function even if you executed it in the same context.

Comment: @NicolBolas This snippet is high level pseudo code. I have edited the question to reflect that. Sorry about that. You can assume that the texture was bound after `glGenTextures` and necessary state was set. Also, this snippet works perfectly fine in the same context but doesn't work for different shared contexts.

Comment: "*Also, this snippet works perfectly fine in the same context but doesn't work for different shared contexts*" The fact that you can get away with something doesn't mean it "worked".

Comment: @NicolBolas Fair enough. I understand that lot of other things could go wrong. My question is theoretical. Let's say I have correctly setup code (everything is done in accordance to the spec) which creates texture and sets the parameter in a single context. Should it also work if I move the parameter setting to a different a shared context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object state changes propagate between contexts in accord with the rules in Section 5.3 of the standard. These are quite detailed and complex. But in general, propagating such changes requires two things: ensuring that the function's setting the state have completed execution, and explicitly binding the object (directly or indirectly) in the new context.

So in order to use the object in context B, you must first ensure the completion of the creation operation in context A. And a CPU mutex alone isn't sufficient; you need to use `glFinish` or wait on a sync object in context A (the sending context). And this command must "happen before" context B's use of it.

To access the updates to the stored state of the object, context B must bind that object (after the above wait has completed for context A). DSA functions do not act as binding operations, so even if you want to use DSA, you must bind the object's first.